# How do I put that at the end of each of the regex patterns of the 4 options, one more numeric character cannot be placed at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regexp-replace

```py
import re

input_text = "empezaran durante el transcurso del mes de enero del 2023" #example

#This is a multiple choice regex (4 options in this case)
input_text_substring = re.sub(r"(?:del[\s|]*mes[\s|]*01|del[\s|]*mes[\s|]*1|del[\s|]*01|del[\s|]*1)", "del mes de enero", input_text_substring, 1)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

Option 1 :

`del[\s|]*mes[\s|]*01` (then there can NOT be immediately a number)

Option 2 :

`del[\s|]*mes[\s|]*1` (then there can NOT be immediately a number)

Option 3 :

`del[\s|]*01` (then there can NOT be immediately a number)

Option 4 :

`del[\s|]*1` (then there can NOT be immediately a number)

I want at the end of each of these 4 options `(?: | | | )` to find a pattern that prevents the next character in the capturing group from being a numeric character `\d`

For example, in this case where the patterns are being used as a replacement condition, if it is not established that immediately after the last character of the pattern there is no numeric character `\d` , this wrong replacement will come up...

```
'durante el transcurso del mes de enero del mes de febrero023'
```

Comment: Append `(?!\d)` at the end

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much, I have added `"(?:del[\s|]*mes[\s|]*01|del[\s|]*mes[\s|]*1|del[\s|]*01|del[\s|]*1)(?!\d)"` there and it works!